# High note =high energy?

Tags: voice

Does a higher note always needs more energy to sing than a lower note? Is it possible for a singer to sing a higher note using same energy used to sing a lower note?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a higher note does not necessarily require more energy to sing. A simple example is the use of [falsetto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsetto) which can be done with very little effort—certainly less than the same singer singing the same pitch using their [modal voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_voice).

Comment: No problem. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @ David Vogel, Yes,that answers my question.We can use this information while producing electronic sound.